# what does HEAD:path/to/dir mean in git archive command?

Tags: git

I am trying to extra a single file from my git repo.  I know there are a ton of answers about how to do this, but all the answers are too general for a dummy like me.  Here is what I have tried:

```
[redcricket@ws-redcricket-l ~]$ git archive --remote=git-server:/opt/git/RED-repo.git development HEAD:apps/scripts  myscript.sh
...
redcricket@git-server's password:
remote: fatal: path not found: HEAD:apps/scripts
remote: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
fatal: sent error to the client: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
```

I am trying to get the file `myscripts.sh`.  If I do a `git clone ...` the file is there, but `git clone` doesn't need this `HEAD:path/to/directory` string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To "extract" as single file from your local repository you can use:

```
git show HEAD:path/to/file
```

Of course you can refer to any commit (tag,branch,sha1,etc.) instead of `HEAD`.

If you really want to use `git archive` to access a remote repository without cloning it first, you can use:

```
git archive --remote=$URL HEAD path/to/file | tar xf -
```

Comment: Yes, but what is unclear to me is what do I replace `path/to/file` with?  Can I just do: `git show HEAD:/tmp/myscript.sh` ?

Comment: If your repository contains a directory `tmp` which contains a file `myscript.sh` and you want to display its version in commit HEAD you use `git show HEAD:tmp/myscript.sh`. (You always have to specify the complete path in the repostitory, therefore no starting `/` is used.)

Comment: I figured out what I need to do: `git archive --remote=git-server:/opt/git/RED-repo.git development apps/scripts/myscript.sh | tar -xf -`